# Booting Ubuntu on a different computer

Tags: boot, system-installation

I installed UBUNTU 12.04, and installed Linus' last kernel (3.14) and it boot fine on my computer. I took the hard disk and put it on another computer and it didn't succeed to boot from my HD and moved to the next boot item (from lan).

Secure boot is disabled on the bios.

I also tried disabling UEFI.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem and a long solution, surely there is a quicker one.

Because I installed Ubuntu with UEFI boot enabled, it matched the grub - meaning it used grub EFI.

I disabled it (UEFI boot), and reinstalled and it used grub-pc and it worked fine afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues as for your question:
The other computer has only this HD as storage right? Usually you can't simply boot a computer with HD replaced. I think there are hardware specific information on ROM that you have to setup your BIOS to configure the HD you put in.
If you use the HD as an external drive, then you have to setup BIOS to boot from it and this HD must be bootable, like a liveCD.

Comment: Yes, this is the only HD. I'm not sure I understand what you described about the need to setup the BIOS, I don't use the HD as external drive - shouldn't the HD be bootable since it is bootable on the original computer?

Comment: no, not necessarily. The HD can be locked so only the original computer can read it. Are the two computer the same model? if not, I doubt you can do that. But anyway, check your BIOS to see the hard disk information, see if it's in the bootable device list, and is there any password protection.

Comment: If the HD is listed on the Boot Drive Order as a bootable device, does it count?

Comment: Could it be Grub issues? currently I have GRUB EFI which was installed by the ubuntu installation. I also tried using the "ubuntu app store" to remove the previous grubs (EFI) and install a regular grub-pc. Still no effect.